# Is this algebraic expression a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I'm having a hard time finding the rules to identify monomials I know a monomial cannot have variables below the square root sign, I try to find in Google a monomial rule where it cannot have a variable as an index in the square root but not found any, I'm testing my self in Khan Academy about identifying polynomials but [the example below I get it wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeVVF.png), could you verify why is this not a polynomial?

$$\sqrt[k]{23} + k$$

Comment: $23^{1/k}$ is not a polynomial because in a polynomial the letter is the base and the exponent is an integer

Comment: @Raffaele So in a monomial always the variables are the base and never the exponent, right?

Comment: The indeterminate letter, I mean the $x$ in $P(x)$ is the base. Like in $P(x)=x^3+2x-1$. The function $f(x)=2^x-3x+1$ is not a polynomial. Letters can be in the exponent like in $P(x)=x^{2n}+x^n+1$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: I get it now, so the base is the indeterminate letter always and never the exponent, right?

Comment: Right. This is correct

Comment: Thanks, @Raffaele! :)

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial is an expression of the form

$$
a_0  + a_1 T + \ldots + a_n T^n \tag{1}
$$

where $n \geq 0$ is some natural number and each $a_i$ are constants in your favourite "set of numbers", say, each $a_i$ can be a real number.

In your example, you have something of the form

$$
a_0^T + a_1T
$$

where $a_1 = 1, a_0 = \sqrt{23}$ which is not of the aforementioned form.

Moreover, even if polynomials can be thought of as functions $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ in some cases, one should **not** in general treat $T$ as a number; $T$ is a "placeholder", an indeterminate. There is (a priori) no meaning for doing $a_0$ to the power of $T$.